# writing html using php

Tags: php, html

folder `g_burqa`:

```
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
...
```

php

```
$files = glob("g_burqa/" . '*.jpg');
foreach($files as $img) { 
        echo "<img src=" . $img . " alt='img'>";
        echo "\n";
    }
```

result:

```
<img src=g_burqa/01.jpg alt='img'>
<img src=g_burqa/02.jpg alt='img'>
<img src=g_burqa/03.jpg alt='img'>
...
```

It's ok but I need `just in the first line` to add a class:

```
<img class="act" src=g_burqa/01.jpg alt='img'>
```

The rest of images are without class.

Any idea?

Comment: Set a simple flag before starting the loop, or use a counter variable.

Comment: I suppose down votes are because of the word `burqa`. But I'm creating a site in order to help to stop the burqa. You are so...

Comment: @bonaca really?? Or because you just dropped an "I want" and waited for the solution?

Comment: @CBroe, maybe it's trivial for you, but I'm writing the above code for last two hours. You should stop being so arrogant, and learn something from people bellow, who just answered the question.

Comment: After that burqa-comment above, I’m not even gonna discuss any more … this can only go the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$files = glob("g_burqa/" . '*.jpg');
$cs=" class=\"someclass\"";
foreach($files as $img) { 
    echo "<img".$cs." src=" . $img . " alt='img'>";
    $cs="";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Like CBroe mentioned, just set your class string before the loop, and then after the first time printing it, set that variable to an empty string. That way it only shows the first time through.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a flag to see if it is first. If so, add the class.

```
$first = true;    
$files = glob("g_burqa/" . '*.jpg');
foreach($files as $img) { 
    $class = ($first) ? ' class="act"' : '';
    $first = false;
    echo "<img src=" . $img . " alt='img'" . $class . ">";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hm, I might just use this one for myself ;-) nothing goes to waste

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple flag, `$first` to do this:

```
$first = true;
$files = glob("g_burqa/" . '*.jpg');
foreach($files as $img) { 
    echo "<img src=" . $img . " alt='img'" . ($first) ? ' class="act"' : "" . ">";
    echo "\n";
    $first = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an increment at the end of the loop and then check if its the first record.

```
$i = 1

foreach($files as $img){
     echo '<img';
      if ($i == 1) { echo ' class="act"'; }
     echo ' src="' . $img .  '" />':
     ++$i
}
```